# PHP How to descending sort tree child's by param

Tags: php, sorting, tree

I have  a tree like this

```
array(
array('name'=>'n1', 'timestamp'=>1000, 'children'=> array()),
array('name'=>'n2', 'timestamp'=>2000, 'children'=> array(
    array('name'=>'n3', 'timestamp'=>3000, 'children'=> array()),
    array('name'=>'n4', 'timestamp'=>4000, 'children'=> array(
        array('name'=>'n5', 'timestamp'=>4000, 'children'=> array()),
        array('name'=>'n6', 'timestamp'=>3000, 'children'=> array())
    )), 
)),
array('name'=>'n7', 'timestamp'=>3000, 'children'=> array())
)

-n1
-n2
    -n3
    -n4
        -n5
        -n6
-n7
```

and I would like to sort it by timestamp on each level DESC, so in result will be

```
-n7
-n2
    -n4
        -n5
        -n6
    -n3
-n1
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: so I found a solution function mysort($node1, $node2) {
 if ($node1['timestamp'] == $node2['timestamp']) return 0;
 return ($node1['timestamp'] > $node2['timestamp']) ? -1 : 1;
}


function sortme(&$data) {
 usort($data, "mysort");
 foreach ($data as $key=>$node)
  if (isset($node['children']) && count($node['children']) >0)
   sortme($data[$key]['children']);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function timestamp_sort(&$a, &$b)
{
  if (!empty($a['children']))
    usort($a['children'], 'timestamp_sort');
  if ($a['timestamp'] == $b['timestamp'])
    return 0;
  return $a['timestamp'] < $b['timestamp'] ? 1 : -1;
}

usort($tree, 'timestamp_sort');
```

I'm assuming you're familiar with the `usort` function - if not, you should read the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

Beyond the basic usage of `usort` we're doing 2 additional things:

- Sorting recursively - the `timestamp_sort` function calls itself when the array contains items that themselves need to be sorted.
- Passing the parameters to the function by reference - that way when we do sort the child arrays, our changes update the original array. Again, if you're not familiar with references, you should [read up on it](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).